# ASCII em Python

Tags: python, string, ascii

Olá. Venho do C e estou começando a aprender Python. Estou com uma questão para deslocar os caracteres de uma string 3 posições e em C ficaria algo assim:

```
str[i] += 3;
```

Tentei fazer a mesma coisa em Python e acabou gerando um erro. Sendo assim, como posso avançar 3 posições de um caractere na linguagem Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução mais flexível para quando tem de fazer muitas alterações na `string` é guarda-la como uma lista utilizando `list`:

```
texto = list("o seu texto aqui")
```

Isto faz com que quando mostra o seu conteúdo, este apareça como numa lista normal:

```
>>> texto
['o', ' ', 's', 'e', 'u', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', 'o', ' ', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'i']
```

Desta forma será possível de alterar cada uma das posições livremente, tal como estava a fazer:

```
>>> texto[2] = chr(ord(texto[2]) + 1)
>>> texto
['o', ' ', 't', 'e', 'u', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', 'o', ' ', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'i']
```

Repare que não pode simplesmente somar um caratere com um numero. Primeiro tem de ir buscar o valor *ascii* da letra com a função [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), somar com o valor que quer, e voltar a converter para caratere com [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr).

E sempre que quiser voltar a mostrar como uma string normal, basta utilizar o [método join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> ''.join(texto)
'o teu texto aqui'
```

Comment: Realmente assim é bem mais interessante de se fazer. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, como strings são imutáveis em Python toda operação em cima de uma string gera uma nova string. Sendo assim uma forma de resolver o seu problema seria:

```
str="ABBBCD"
index=1
str = str[:index] + chr(ord(str[index]) + 3) + str[index + 1:]
print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = str('SVL#d#wxd#glvflsolqd#suhihulgd$$')

decode = []

for letter in string:

    decoded = int(ord(letter))

    code = chr(decoded + 3)

    decode.append(code)

print(decode)
```